# Find object based on RLMArray item property

Tags: objective-c, realm

I'm trying to make a search operation over a collection of Realm objects based on the identifier of an object stored as item in a RLMArray on the main object. Just like this two models:

```
// Person model
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property int personID;
@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end

// Dog model
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property int dogID;
@property NSString *name;
@property int age; // Some other random properties
@end
```

So, as you can see, we have a `RLMArray` of dogs property for each person.

The query: Given a `dogID`, how can I query the database to get the owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a "direct" method for this answer. I didn't thought about Inverse Relationships for the database. We just need to create a `RLMLinkingObjects` property on the child objects:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property int dogID;
@property NSString *name;
@property int age; // Some other random properties
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *owners;
@end

@implementation Dog
+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
        @"owners": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Person.class propertyName:@"dogs"],
    };
}
@end
```

From this point you just query for the ID of the `Dog` and then look for the `owners` property to get the owner (if it's just one owner it's an array of one element.)

Details are in the documentation: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#inverse-relationships